# Determining CSS Specificity Score

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-specificity

How do I calculate the specificity score for these declaration blocks:

`body div main section div ul li p strong span a {}`

Specificity = 1*11=11

and,

`.someClass {}`

Specificity = 10 * 1 = 10

So, will the first one win?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[W3C specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity) states:

> A selector's specificity is calculated as follows:
>
> - count the number of ID selectors in the selector (= a)
> - count the number of class selectors, attributes selectors, and    pseudo-classes in the selector (= b)
> - count the number of type selectors and pseudo-elements in the    selector (= c)
> - ignore the universal selector
>
> Selectors inside the negation pseudo-class are counted like any other,
>   but the negation itself does not count as a pseudo-class.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> *               /* a=0 b=0 c=0 -> specificity =   0 */
> LI              /* a=0 b=0 c=1 -> specificity =   1 */
> UL LI           /* a=0 b=0 c=2 -> specificity =   2 */
> UL OL+LI        /* a=0 b=0 c=3 -> specificity =   3 */
> H1 + *[REL=up]  /* a=0 b=1 c=1 -> specificity =  11 */
> UL OL LI.red    /* a=0 b=1 c=3 -> specificity =  13 */
> LI.red.level    /* a=0 b=2 c=1 -> specificity =  21 */
> \#x34y           /* a=1 b=0 c=0 -> specificity = 100 */
> \#s12:not(FOO)   /* a=1 b=0 c=1 -> specificity = 101 */
> ```
>
> Concatenating the three numbers a-b-c (in a number system with a large base) gives the specificity.

---

Now I will try to make it clear how it is actually implemented. Ie. 10 htmls tags do not equal one class, it goes more like this:

`id : class : tag :  pseudo-elements`

---

First example:

```
body div main section div ul li p strong span a {}
```

Specificity: `0 : 0 : 11 : 0`

Second example:

```
.someClass {}
```

Specificity: `0 : 1 : 0 : 0`

11 elements will win not with one class. Higher tier always wins, so even more than 1000 classes will never beat id (styling with id's is rather bad practice anyway).

---

Do not forget about cascade. Styles with the same specificity declared later in source file(s) will win in case of conflict. The inline styles will always win with anything, except of `!important`.